# Formula to calculate groups for graph

Tags: java, jfreechart, formula, graph-algorithm

I working on graphs using JFreeChart library to generate a barchart.

Example Scenario: considering the data will be in arrays/arraylist.

[image]

Using the above table data, I have to generate below table(first 2 columns) and a bar chart

[image]

Method to categories

```
Number of days taken by person into 
Number of people between two days(column 2) and exactly 10 values in x axis.
```

I am looking for a way to get column 2 values and rest I can do by myself. I am happy to provide further information, if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer,

```
always set min = 0
max = maximum number in the column Number of days taken
divide the maximum by 10, interval = max/10
and start from to 0 to interval and  interval to interval+ interval ....,
```